# How to clone an ES6 class object constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Making a simple ORM with ES6 classes, I run with a blocking issues – I can't properly copy a class (as I would have with `util.extend` in ES5).

Specifically, here is what I tried:

```
class BaseModel {

  echo() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  static _setProperties(props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

}

function makeModel(props) {

  // Try to copy the Class object
  const Model = 
      Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(BaseModel)), BaseModel);

  // Copy my static methods – is there a better way to do this?
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(BaseModel).forEach((key) => {
    if (!key.startsWith('_')) return;
    Model[key] = BaseModel[key];
  });

  // Configure the new model
  Model._setProperties(props);
  return Model;
}

const GreeterModel = makeModel('hello');
const greeter = new GreeterModel();
greeter.echo(); // Should log hello
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: GreeterModel is not a constructor
```

Is there any way to achieve this with ES6 classes, or do I have to stick to ES5-style?

*Optional question:* is there a better way to copy the static methods? The solution with `getOwnPropertyNames` is not ideal as it returns also read-only properties, such as `length`.

Thanks!

Comment: `Object.create` does not create functions, this code wouldn't work with ES5 either.

Comment: Why not just use ES6 `class extends`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a logic mistake in your base class. `this` always depends on how a function is called. A static function is usually called on the constructor, i.e. `BaseModel._setProperties(...)` in which case `this` refers to `BaseModel`.
Instance methods however are called on an the instance itself, therefore `this` refers to the instance not the constructor.

To make `BaseModel` work you would have to use

```
echo() {
  console.lof(this.constructor.props);
}
```

But to answer your actual question, you can simply extend the class:

```
function makeModel(props) {
  class Model extends BaseModel {}
  Model._setProperties(props);
  return Model;
}
```

Note that this is isn't "cloning" the base class, it's extending it. There is no reasonable way to clone a function in JavaScript (not so far fat least).